# ESXi Fault Tolerance Network Issue - FT traffic flooded?

Tags: performance, vmware-esxi, switch, vmware-vsphere, fault-tolerance

I've setup a 2-nodes vSphere cluster. Each node is equipped with 4x1GE NICs. I have set a single vSwitch in each node, using all 4 vmnics as adapters and the following ports:

> Management: vmKernel port -> Active on vmnic0, Standby on vmnic1-2-3
>
> vMotion and FT -> Active on vmnic3, Standby on vmnic0-1-2
>
> Workload -> Active on vmnic0-1-2-3
>
> Route based on originating virtual port.

I know the solution is not ideal, as best practices suggest to have a physically separated network for vMotion/FT, but still.

I noticed that no VM is mapped to vmnic3, so this appears to be used by vMotion/FT only.

However when FT is enabled (on a dummy WinServer machine doing nothing), I notice the following issues:

1) pings to/from that machine go unstable (up to 5ms)

2) capturing stats on the physical switch, I noticed the port physically connected to vMotion/FT NIC has an input rate of 300Mbps (which is expected), but I also notice the output rate of all ports connected to other vmnics go 300Mbps, **like the physical switch flood FT traffic on all other ports**. When disabling FT, traffic go back to small values on all NICs.

Why points 1 and 2 above?

**EDIT**: All ports are in the same VLAN. I know this is far from ideal, but still can't explain points 1 and 2 above

Comment: Why don't you create separate VMKernel ports on individual NIC's instead of using all 4 NIC's? That way you have a dedicated NIC for VM's, another for FT, another for vMotion, etc.? Why did you create a single vSwitch with all 4 NIC's?

Comment: Can you tell us the VLAN configuration of each portgroup?

Comment: @joeqwerty for redundancy

Comment: @DanielK question edited adding this info

Comment: The recommendation is to use 10Gbps networking.

Answer (score 1):

The traffic is called **'unicast flooding'** and it happens when the switch is unsure where to direct the packets to.

There is a known problem with unicast flooding occurring when vMotion ports are not isolated in their own VLAN. VMware are not as clear about this as they should be and there is a good blog post on it here: http://virtuallyhyper.com/2012/03/vmotion-causes-unicast-flooding/.

Your assignments of NICs to the services is fine, but you must use a dedicated VLAN for vMotion traffic. Your switchports would need to be trunk ports to accommodate this.

Comment: interesting. However I don't experience flooding during vMotion (manually migrating a VM) but only when Fault Tolerance is on. Is this expected?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough bandwidth for Fault Tolerance. [VMware recommends at least 10 Gb/s links.](https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/techpaper/performance/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-67-performance-best-practices.pdf)  [In the lab, even a 2 vCPU VM needs about 2.5 Gb/s just for FT, in some scenarios.](https://www.vmware.com/techpapers/2016/vmware-vsphere-6-fault-tolerance-architecture-and-10514.html) That is what is required to replicate the change rate of RAM.

Re-examine your recovery time requirements. Non-FT VMware HA can boot a VM on a different host with a couple minutes downtime.

If you are serious about FT, consider dedicating 3 or 4 of those 1 Gb links to FT, or upgrade to something like 25 Gb Ethernet.

Comment: how this could explain the flooding?

Comment: Bandwidth alone does not explain the flooding. Probably the trouble is introduced by sharing switchports for different purposes. But you will want to dedicate more than 1 Gb to FT when you fix that.